# Trying to connect to my Rails web app results in a directory listing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, passenger

```
Rails 3.2.18
Ruby 2.1.5
Capistrano
Apache2
Phusion Passenger
Ubuntu 14.04.2
```

I have been using Capistrano to deploy my application. The set of commands that Capistrano executes (after connecting to the repo and copying all the files):

```
cd /home/myapp/current
RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile
cp /home/myapp/shared/assets/manifest.yml /home/myapp/current/assets_manifest.yml
touch /home/myapp/current/tmp/restart.txt
echo \"DEPLOY SIDEKIQ RELOAD $(date)\" >> /home/myapp/current/log/sidekiq.log
screen -d -m sh -c 'cd /home/myapp/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sidekiq'
cd /home/myapp/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:stop
cd /home/myapp/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
screen -d -m sh -c 'cd /home/myapp/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex'
```

Recently, following a deployment, instead going into the web application, when I enter the URL, all I see is a directory listing of the /home/myapp/current/public in my browser.

I can start the application manually by doing:

```
cd ~/current
sudo service apache2 stop
rvmsudo bundle exec rails s -e production -p 80 -d
```

The problem here is that some of the Rails app tasks start running as root (writing files, files uploaded, etc), which is problematic and is probably a security risk. Any ideas?

Comment: Was it working before? Have you installed passenger apache2 module?

Comment: Yes, it was working. In my question I listed my environment which includes Apache2 and Phusion Passenger